# how to sort a string array by numbers at start of string?

Tags: java, sorting, methods

in java i have an array list of strings formatted as follows each entry

12,Vanilla granola bar,91.

how can i sort the list in increasing order of the first numbers of each string? would collections.sort() be able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> would collections.sort() be able to do this?

Yes, but, you would need a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) in order to extract the leading values and compare them appropriately

This is a **VERY** basic example of the concept...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomSorter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(25);
        values.add("12,Vanilla granola bar,91");
        values.add("1,Vanilla granola bar,91");
        values.add("50,Vanilla granola bar,91");
        values.add("25,Vanilla granola bar,91");
        values.add("13,Vanilla granola bar,91");

        dump(values);

        Collections.sort(values, new SplitComparator());

        dump(values);
    }

    protected static void dump(List<String> values) {
        System.out.println(values);
    }

    public static class SplitComparator implements Comparator<String> {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            int i1 = getIndex(o1);
            int i2 = getIndex(o2);

            return i1 - i2;
        }

        protected int getIndex(String o1) {
            return Integer.parseInt(o1.split(",")[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

It should be noted that there are simply so many things that could go wrong it's not funny.  I've made no checks to determine it either of the `String`s to be compared actually meet the requirements of the `Comparator`, nor do I handle cases where the first element is not a number for example.

A better solution would be to wrap you `String` values into a POJO or `interface` and provide appropriate appropriate getters.  This would allow you to restrict the `Comparator` to a specific type of class, making it safer

Comment: @LittleChild Don't you hate it when that happens ;)

Comment: a lot more when it is you hahaha

Comment: @LittleChild That's what I'm here for :D